# Substitute A for B and B for A in a string

Tags: r, regex

I want to substitute all `A`'s for `B`'s and `B`'s for `A`'s in a string in R.

My input is

```
x = "ABCDBBABDC"
```

and my output should be,

```
y = "BACDAABADC"
```

How could I do this in one line?

I tried `sub` but I cannot do multiple substitutions.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have gotten the job. Wudda repl'd the A's with "|", the B's with A's, and the "|'s with B. Mahto's sol'n was much kewler.

Comment: I am curious why the requirement for one line?

Comment: @Ricardo, no real need, just cool to have a one liner ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for `chartr`:

```
x = "ABCDBBABDC"
chartr("AB", "BA", x)
# [1] "BACDAABADC"
```

Comment: I think `chartr` is one of those under appreciated functions like `ave` that need a better advertising agency.

Comment: @Dwin, absolutely with you on this one.  I didnt even know this function exsited